# Linux IP forwarding trouble

Tags: linux, networking, centos, redhat, route

In my environment most of the servers have 2 network cards.  A
primary/user network card used by the application, and a secondary/backup 
adapter used for backups, bulk copies etc.

I just set up a new server and have a problem pinging its
secondary adapter from a clients that only have a primary/user
adapter.

From my test client I am able to ping my other servers on their
primary/secondary adapters.

**The Networks:**

- 192.168.151.0 == user network with my servers
- 192.168.147.0 == user network with my client
- 192.168.245.0 == backup network

**The Computers:**

newServer (rhel 6)   [ a.k.a. the troublemaker]

- eth0 : 192.168.151.180  (user network)
- eth1 : 192.168.245.187  (backup network)

oldServer (rhel 5)

- eth0 : 192.168.151.203  (user network)
- eth1 : 192.168.245.236  (backup network)

pubClient (rhel5)   [client system with only a user interface]

- eth0 : 192.168.147.118   (user)

From pubClient I can ping oldServer on either its eth0 or eth1 ip addresses. I noticed (tcpdump) that when I ping eth1, the return path of the ping is the eth0 interface of oldServer.

From pubClient I can ping newServer's eth0 interface, but when I ping newServer's eth1 adapter nothing happens. Using tcpdump I see the traffic coming in to the backup network 
interface, but no traffic coming out.  The eth1 adapter is working fine - from newServer I can ping other devices on the backup network using the 245 interface, or pubClient without any indication of a problem.

The routing tables on both servers are simple and
functionally identical.

```
newServer # ip route list
192.168.151.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.151.180
192.168.245.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.245.187
default via 192.168.151.5 dev eth0

oldServer # ip route list
192.168.151.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.151.203
192.168.245.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.245.236
default via 192.168.151.5 dev eth2
```

There are no firewalls running on either box.  `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0`
on both servers.  The newServer is running RHEL6 I wonder if a default
for some kind of network traversal (like ip_forward) has been disabled 
by default?

My network guys insist nothing is wrong with the routing between these machines.

**Any guesses to what the problem might be would be appreciated.**

Cheers

-Scott

Comment: I am not sure, but this might be a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/595386/packets-returning-but-traceroute-fails/595393

Comment: do you have access to the default gateway at 192.168.151.5 ?
how does it route to 192.168.147.118 ?
what routes does pubClient have ?
does any of these machines have iptables running (and/or blocking icmp)?

Comment: Yes.  From the machines in question, I can ping the gateways and ip tables is not running.  I think I need to take this back to our network team again to verify their configuration.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Thanks Wayne.

On the new (rhel6 server)

```
echo "0" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/rp_filter
echo "0" >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/rp_filter
```

"uRPF check does is looks at the source address of the 
packets as they come in.  If the route to that source 
address would not go out that interface then the packet 
is dropped"

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.kernel.html